# CSS - How to make button beside input text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place button beside input text

※ example [input text][button]

And button size should be fixed.

- Even though the window size change, button size should be fixed and should be beside input text.

Below is my code.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>...</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code makes button move when window size is small.
And also makes button small, so that unavailable to see value inside button.

I want to know how to code as I expect.

Comment: You should tag with [tag:bootstrap] also, if you are using bootstrap.

Comment: @JoSSte I tried but system won't let me tag bootstrap

Comment: @Junie Bootstrap has been made by twitter few yeas ago, so StackOverflow have now decided to rename it `twitter-bootstrap` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous one did not work,
Please try this.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button>  
     </div>
  </div>
```

hope this one helps.

Comment: Yeah This one helped me. Thanks! But have another question. Is there any possible way to make space between input and button? Tried using m-l-10 on input group append class part but not worked..

Comment: Yup , use mr-2 on input instead of m-l-2.

Comment: Which will look like this :  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Search">

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime ! And don't forget to vote up as well if any of our answer helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the layout for mobile devices you can use col-xs-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-2 (if you are using bootstrap 3) if you are using bootstrap 4 you can use only col-2 col-8 col-2. But if your screen size is small, grid makes your button small according to your screensize.

Comment: Nope.. editing col-sm- to col- does not make what I expect.

Comment: I need answer to put button beside input text. Which button size does not change when I resize window..

Answer (score 0):

**Here the class i've used is from bootstrap. This will solve your problem**

```
<form style="margin-left: 100px;" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="uname">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" style="width: 30%">               
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="width: 20%;">Log In</button><br>
            </form>
```